# Jira development - set affected version

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I have problems to update an Issue with affected versions....
The version, where version was retrieve with VersionManager.
But I don't understand why after the validateUpdate method, the validateVersionUpdate has not any data of affectedVersion. Validation don't give any error, and the version and issue are in the same project. Any idea?

```
MutableIssue componentUpdateSubTask = subtaskIssue.getIssue(); 
IssueInputParameters versionValues = issueService.newIssueInputParameters();
versionValues.setAffectedVersionIds(version.getId());
UpdateValidationResult validateVersionUpdate = issueService.validateUpdate(applicationUser, componentUpdateSubTask.getId(), versionValues);
if (!validateVersionUpdate.isValid()) { 
      throw new Exception(validateVersionUpdate); } 
IssueResult versionResult = issueService.update(applicationUser, validateVersionUpdate); 
if (!versionResult.isValid()) {  
     throw new Exception(versionResult);   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally the code is working correctly. That what was wrong where some settings in the project. I had to set the Affected Version field as editable.

Answer (score 0):

i hope following link will help you
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/97829/cannot-set-new-affects-version-s